# How can I find multiple solutions for a system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, linear-programming

I'm writing a program for CheckIO.org that is supposed to return an array,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end {bmatrix}
$$
, that satisfies the System of Equations
$$
A
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end {bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
225\\
315
\end {bmatrix}
$$
(where $A$ is a given matrix), where all elements of 'xyz' are integers. I've tried Gaussian elimination and Cramer's rule, but each method only gives one answer and the elements are floats. I also tried $\vec{x} = \vec{b}*A^{-1}$, but that returned the wrong answer.

Comment: For a given matrix $A$ i's very improbable that $x,y,z$ are integers. Or your problem is to find $A$ such that these are integers?

Comment: What were the outputs? Using a strong type language or dynamic?

Comment: @ EmilioNovati — I am given A, and am supposed to find \begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end {bmatrix}. I already know that the problem in question has two integer solutions, but I don't know how to find more than one without using brute force. My code currently uses Gaussian elimination, and an [online solver](http://www.mathportal.org/calculators/system-of-equations-solver/system-3x3.php) that I found gets the same answer that my code does, but that answer is "wrong" since it isn't one of the integer solutions.

@ Chinny84 — CheckIO uses Python.